# Dual Booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to dual boot my computer with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04, but I keep running into a problem. I have created a primary partition for the new OS, have downloaded the 64-bit .iso file (my computer is a 64-bit machine) from the Ubuntu website, burned it to a disc, and then restarted the computer while the disc was still in the drive. When the computer tried to boot from the disc, I got a kernel panic. How can I change this so that I don't keep getting kernel panics?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to your kernel panic problem.

But have you considered using the Ubuntu windows installer Wubi?

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

I've used it in the past with success and ease. It is a Ubuntu installer that you can run directly in Windows. I believe the Ubuntu OS is installed under the Windows file system but you will be able to boot directly into Ubuntu from the boot loader.

Comment: I'd rather have it on a separate partition though....

Answer (score 0):

Before burning, check the signature of the Ubuntu `.iso` file. The signatures (Ubuntu hashes) are available on Ubuntu's website. It ensures that the downloaded file is correct. There is an utility for Windows for reading hashes from `.iso` files.

It may so happen that the CD is not properly prepared. You can try another CD. Burn it with low speed. You may try installing from USB also.